# Any way to render date with microseconds?

Tags: php, twig

Is there any way to render a string that represents the current time with microseconds when you don't have access to twig instance? I mean, it's only possible to work with a template and it's **NOT** possible to extend twig in any way.

With the following template:

```
{{ "now"|date("Ymd_His") }}
```

I can get the date + time fractions, but the desired result would be

```
20150616_202042.123456
               ^-- here is the most interesting part
```

So any chance for a *pure template based* solution?

I have made a research and all I could find implied extending twig engine, which I cannot do in the current case.

**UPD**: the solution I'm looking for is not limited by using `date()` function explicitly and may use anything that is allowed in a twig template.

**UPD 2**: It's not a symfony2 application. It's not a web application either.

Comment: Since the twig filter date is based on php's date() function, i don't think that microseconds can be displayed, since date takes a UNIX timestamp as integer for its time argument.

Comment: @EJTH I'm not limited in using `date` function only. The desired solution may use anything that is allowed to be used in a twig template.

Comment: You could try `"now"|date("Ymd_His.u")` but you will probably just get 0 for microseconds.

Comment: @EJTH yep, that's `0` for `u` :-)

Comment: I researched it a bit, and I don't think that you can do something like this without extending twig. :-(

Comment: @EJTH yep, if it was trivial I wouldn't ask :-)

Comment: Eventhough you can't extend twig, can you inject variables into the template? If so you could pass in a proper DateTime object with microseconds, and then date() filter should work on that.

Comment: @EJTH I would qualify it as an answer. Not ideal, but pretty much acceptable and fitting my limitations.

Comment: Just tested it, and it didn't work for me. Must be because date() filter is based on PHP date function. You could just pass in the desired formatted date though, that would probably be the easiest.

Comment: It looks like twig doesn't have any sort of "call native php code" type function, which is what you would need to get microseconds, since normal date() values don't have microseconds. DateTime objects do, but if twig is actually formatting the DateTime object into an epoch date, the microseconds would be lost before getting to `date()`

Comment: @EJTH well, how about using `DateTime::format()` instead of `date()`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're going to work with current time only, you can always use request params (available since PHP 5.4.0):

```
{{ app.request.server.get('REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT') }}
```

This is related to Symfony2 of course.

Comment: It's neither a symfony2 application, nor a web application at all. But thanks :-)

Comment: Ok, my bad I didn't asked for it earlier

Comment: It's okay, sorry I didn't mention it in the question (now I have)